# XSSF saving workbook

Tags: excel, apache-poi, xssf

I am using XSSF to create a workbook and continually getting this error:

Excel found unreadable content in 'thefile'.xlsx. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of the workbook click Yes.
Excel then obligingly recovers it by removing all of the data and gives the detail error report:
Removed Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

I am following these principles:
Ensure the row is created and not null.
Ensure the cell is created and not null.
Ensure the cell is the correct type.
Write to cell.

Is there something I am missing, eg is it permissable to have only certain cells written to in a row eg:

|null|null|write something here|null|null|

and the same with rows:

---

row with content

---

null

---

row with content

---

or do I need to ensure the all rows and columns are filled blank through the ranges used.
This is a complete mystery.

Comment: Woah found out that some of these cause errorssaving with the active cell on a null row

Comment: @Tim...One more case adding after yours... You can get this in case you have deleted the Active Sheet as well. So just for Precaution, before deleting any sheet, change active Sheet of the workbook to other sheet.

Comment: @Tim, if you got the solution, either post it and accept that or remove this question, as it is of no use for the other viewers.